# p4 integrate uncommitted changelist to same branch

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, perforce

I will be syncing from perforce based on last committed change no and run the build. My requirement is to integrate a particular uncommitted changelist to the workspace where i have synced my code from perforce.

I using p4 plugin and building via jenkins

Comment: Are you asking about the syntax of the 'p4 unshelve' command?

Comment: Yes, If p4 unshelve can be used to integrate pending changelist without committing. No idea on shelve/unshelve.  Please help

Answer (score 1):

In Perforce, changelists can be pending, shelved, or submitted.

A pending changelist's modified files are only stored on the workstation where the work was done.

Shelved and submitted changelists are stored on the server, and can be accessed by other workspaces, on other client workstations.

Submitted changelists are permanent (except for administrative commands such as `p4 obliterate`).

A shelved changelist contains a snapshot of work-in-progress, copied up to the server when the developer issues the `p4 shelve` command.

A shelved changelist can be unshelved to a different workspace, so that another developer (or a build-and-test machine) can experiment with the shelved changes (build them, run tests, etc.)

The developer who originally shelved the changelist can subsequently update it with further changes, or can delete it, or can submit it. They can also simply leave it in its shelved state.

To access the file modifications contained in the shelved changelist, use the `p4 unshelve` command; you must know the shelved changelist number in order to issue this command (and there are other restrictions as you might expect: you have to have those files mapped into your workspace, the protections table must allow you to open those files for edit in your workspace, etc.). When you run the `p4 unshelve` command, the files will be opened in your workspace, and the file contents will be set to contain the contents that the developer who owns the shelve used when they created the shelf.

Shelves are a great way for different users (or automated tools) to work with changes before they are submitted; I greatly encourage you to read the documentation about the `p4 shelve` and `p4 unshelve` commands and experiment with them until you feel comfortable with the way they work.

Comment: I tried p4 unshelve `p4 unshelve -s 123445`, where the response from p4 is 'file is unshelved and opened for edit'. but the change is not reflected in the workspace. only the previouis existing version of the file is available

Comment: If the file in question was already opened in your workspace, `p4 unshelve` will have scheduled a resolve. Try `p4 resolve` next.